# The object changes when accessing it in the multiprocess manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I create a `Manager` of multiprocesses

```
def manager():
    m = SyncManager()
    m.start()
    return m
```

I have object

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name = "joe"):
        self.name = name
    def bark(self):
        print("woof")
```

Register it

```
SyncManager.register("Dog", Dog)
```

Create instance

```
lab = mg.Dog("carl")
```

Create shared dict

```
m = manager().dict()
```

Set object to dict

```
m[1] = lab
```

When I try to access this object I have troubles

```
>>> id(m[1])
4378037600
>>> id(m[1])
4378036208
```

How can fix it?

Updated:

```
class MoneyManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_signals_count = 0

    def add_signal(self):
        self.active_signals_count += 1


class MMPool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mm = {}

    def add_mm(self, mm: MoneyManager, profile: StrategyProfile):
        self.mm[profile] = mm

    def remove_mm(self, profile_id: int):
        self.mm.pop(profile_id, None)

    def get_mm(self, profile: StrategyProfile):
        return self.mm.get(profile)


class Strategy:
    @staticmethod
    def handle_pair(profile, shared_dict):
        mm_pool = shared_dict["mm_pool"]
        money_manager = mm_pool.get_mm(profile)
        money_manager.add_signal()
        mm_pool.add_mm(money_manager, profile)
        shared_dict["mm_pool"] = mm_pool
        mm_pool = shared_dict["mm_pool"]
        money_manager = mm_pool.get_mm(profile)
        print(datetime.now(), f"{profile.id=}, {money_manager.active_signals_count=} \n")


class Command:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mm_pool = MMPool()

    @staticmethod
    def _handle_strategy(shared_dict, strategy):
        for i in range(2):
            strategy.handle_pair(shared_dict)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        strategies = StrategyProfile.objects.all()

        mm_pool = {}
        for profile in StrategyProfile.objects.all():
            if not mm_pool.get(profile.mm_profile):
                money_manager = MoneyManager()
                mm_pool[profile.mm_profile] = money_manager
            self.mm_pool.add_mm(mm_pool[profile.mm_profile], profile)

        shared_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

        while True:
            with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=strategies.count()) as executor:
                if "mm_pool" not in shared_dict:
                    shared_dict["mm_pool"] = self.mm_pool
                processes = [executor.submit(shared_dict, strategy) for strategy in strategies]
                for _ in processes:
                    ...
```

In the response I get:

```
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.680219 profile.id=1, money_manager.active_signals_count=1 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.683301 profile.id=1, money_manager.active_signals_count=2 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.683548 profile.id=2, money_manager.active_signals_count=2 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.686149 profile.id=2, money_manager.active_signals_count=3
```

But I want to get

```
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.680219 profile.id=1, money_manager.active_signals_count=1 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.683301 profile.id=1, money_manager.active_signals_count=2 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.683548 profile.id=2, money_manager.active_signals_count=2 
signal_generator            | 
signal_generator            | 2022-03-29 22:26:21.686149 profile.id=2, money_manager.active_signals_count=4
```

Comment: What? What is the trouble exactly?

Comment: The object changes when you look at the id

Comment: The object didn't "change", the manager is returning a *new object*, which is expected. Why did you *expect* it to work differently?

Comment: Is it possible to make the manager return the old object?

Comment: The whole point of a `Manager` is to share objects between processes, each of which has its own independent address space.  It's not even meaningful to speak of "the same object" in different processes, so there's no point in it trying to preserve object identity.

Comment: @jasonharper That is, it is not possible to share an object between two processes?

Comment: No; the best you can hope for is to have equal objects in each process.

Comment: I want changes made in one process to be visible in another process.(

Comment: Right, that's what `Manager` does.  It does it by transmitting changes to the other processes, to keep the objects in sync.  It doesn't mean that they are the *same* object.

Comment: I add full example of my code

Comment: Strange, but sometimes the answer is correct

Comment: Hm... When I added `time.sleep` to second process - I get correct result always

Comment: I solve it with `lock` and `Manager`

Comment: Well done! Feel free to write it up as answer to your own question, you can even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a `Manager` to manage shared objects and a `Lock` to avoid the *race condition*

Then need to pass this `lock` to child processes.

```py
        ....
        shared_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

        while True:
            with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=strategies.count()) as executor:
                m = multiprocessing.Manager()
                lock = m.Lock()
                if "mm_pool" not in shared_dict:
                    shared_dict["mm_pool"] = self.mm_pool
                processes = [executor.submit(self._handle_strategy, shared_dict, lock, strategy) for strategy in strategies]
                for _ in processes:
                    ...
```

And in places where there is a change in the *shared object*, use `lock` with the *context manager*.

```py
    def handle_pair(profile, shared_dict, lock):
        with lock:
            mm_pool = shared_dict["mm_pool"]
            money_manager = mm_pool.get_mm(profile)
            money_manager.add_signal()
            mm_pool.add_mm(money_manager, profile)
            shared_dict["mm_pool"] = mm_pool
            mm_pool = shared_dict["mm_pool"]
            money_manager = mm_pool.get_mm(profile)
            print(datetime.now(), f"{profile.id=}, {money_manager.active_signals_count=} \n")
```